# I want to show 4 random names, but only 1 is displayed on the site

Tags: javascript

I want to show 4 random names, but only the last one is displayed on the site. If I use console.log I do see all 4 names. 
Does someone know how to fix it?

```js
let playerName = ["Phineas", "Ferb", "Spongebob", "Patrick", "Octo", "Sandy", "Krabs"];
let pCreate = document.createElement('p');
let playerSetup = document.getElementById('playerSetup');

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    let x = Math.random()*playerName.length;
    pCreate.innerHTML = playerName[Math.floor(x)];
    playerSetup.appendChild(pCreate);
}
```

```html
<div id="playerSetup"></div>
```

TY :)

Comment: A valid answer is already been given but do note you can get duplicate names with this code. You might want to remove a name from the array after using it to avoid duplicate names.

Comment: Just noticed that :) Ty @MarkBaijens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new `<p>` for each one of your players ! Otherwise you're just replacing it

Just move line 2 in the `for` loop

```js
let playerName = ["Phineas", "Ferb", "Spongebob", "Patrick", "Octo", "Sandy", "Krabs"];
let playerSetup = document.getElementById('playerSetup');

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let x = Math.random() * playerName.length;
  let pCreate = document.createElement('p');
  pCreate.innerHTML = playerName[Math.floor(x)];
  playerSetup.appendChild(pCreate);
}
```

```html
<div id="playerSetup"></div>
```

You can click "Run code snippet" to see the code in action